# Is Guice needed in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, singleton, guice

I was told the Guice is aim to produce testable code, and not needed in the unit test. But how can I test a Singleton(@Singleton) without use Guice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't *need* Guice (or any DI framework) in unit tests, the SUT is normally small enough that manual DI is fine and good.

Now as to how to "test a singleton". The same way you test any other class, that is part of the beauty of singleton-as-a-scope. In your test methods create a new instance of the "singleton", test it and then throw it away. Remember you don't want the SUT to be affected by previous tests and you will want to be able to set different dependencies for each test so the fact that you're using the scope and not the design pattern is a good thing. You don't need to do anything special to test it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, mlk. I've mixed up unit test with integration test.

Comment: Ah. For integration tests I try to use Guice and the live modules for the SUT. After all that is all part of the SUT. You might be interested in Guiceberry if you use JUnit to run your integration tests. 
http://code.google.com/p/guiceberry/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my personal take is that any test that requires DI framework can be viewed with suspicion -- it sounds rather more like an integration test, not unit test.
Unit tests should be stand-alone, and you SHOULD manually and explicitly wire all dependencies, including mock versions of things you don't want to test.
I know that in mainstream dev lingo term "unit test" may be diluted mean any testing written by developers. This does not mean it is proper usage of the term however.

In that light, no, you should have to (and probably just should not!) rely on Guice or Spring DI.

Great thing about Guice (et al) is actually this: by using them for full systems, you make testing without any DI much easier.

So I think the highest rated answer is correct: to test a singleton, just create and test it. There is no specific magic to it.

Comment: I appreciate your point, and at the same time, Java EE hides a lot of an instance's lifecycle behind the scenes, which makes it difficult to inject mocks. I've been struggling with JAX-RS and EntityManager injection for a long time, and I'm giving up testing the actual URIs/@Paths. I now test the methods, but have to trust that I got the @Paths right. I don't like it, so using something like Guice or Spring would be nice. But I'm afraid they don't play nicely with Java EE containers like GlassFish. Ugh!

Comment: I think I should add that I think DI is often not good for UNIT tests; but obviously useful for other tests. And for paths, I actually prefer doing system test from client side. I feel your pain wrt DI, Java EE -- I think it is generational difference, I have grown to think App Servers should go the way of EJB, in favor of simpler components.

Answer (score 1):

Guice does dependency injection, and you need it in tests too, I guess.
Guice make it simple to change implementation for injected classes to mock objects (stubs, not real objects). So your tests can run in stub enviroment and be tested faster and independently of other layers of your app.